# How to save an audio(mp3) from an HTTP response

Tags: node.js, http

There is a GET request which fetches an audio, and when the response arrives I want to save it. I have tried two ways but both ways are not working great.

Below the problem is that the file is not saved entirely. It only saves at max the first 16Kb of the file. I need it entirely.

```
res.on('data', d => {
    this.writeFile(recordingID + ".mp3", "./recordings/", d);
});
```

Below is the second method, the audio is saved entirely but it does not play because it is corrupted.

```
let array = [];
let str = "";
let stringWithoutSpaces;
res.setEncoding('binary');
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
    array.push(chunk);
    stringWithoutSpaces= array.join('');
});

res.on("end", () => {
    try {
        fs.promises
        .writeFile(recordingID + ".mp3", stringWithoutSpaces, {
             encoding: 'utf8'
         })
         .then(() => {
             console.log('Done');
         });
         if (err) throw err
});
```

Comment: `encoding: 'utf8'`? For binary data?

Comment: I removed the binary encoding and kept the UTF-8 encoding and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out, you just need to push all the chunk to an array and then use the buffer to save the file.

```
let array = [];

res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    array.push(chunk);
});

res.on("end", () => {
    try {
        fs.promises
            .writeFile( `${recordingID}.mp3`, Buffer.concat(array), {
                encoding: 'utf8'
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('Done');
            });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
});
```